# Ext.bind does not see function in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am trying to mod the Portlet example and port it into our program. The code looks like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport',{
            id: 'app-viewport', //creates viewport
            layout: {
                type: 'border',
                padding: '0 5 5 5' // pad the layout from the window edges
            },

            onPortletClose: function(portlet) {
                this.showMsg('"' + portlet.title + '" was removed');
            },

            showMsg: function(msg) {
                var el = Ext.get('app-msg'),
                    msgId = Ext.id();

                this.msgId = msgId;
                el.update(msg).show();

                Ext.defer(this.clearMsg, 3000, this, [msgId]);
            },

            clearMsg: function(msgId) {
                if (msgId === this.msgId) {
                    Ext.get('app-msg').hide();
                }
            },

            items: [{
                id: 'app-header',
                xtype: 'box',
                region: 'north',
                height: 40,
                html: 'Ext Welcome'
            },{
                xtype: 'container',
                region: 'center',
                layout: 'border',
                items: [{
                    id: 'app-options', //Creates the Options panel on the left
                    title: 'Options',
                    region: 'west',
                    animCollapse: true,
                    width: 200,
                    minWidth: 150,
                    maxWidth: 400,
                    split: true,
                    collapsible: true,
                    layout:{
                        type: 'accordion',
                        animate: true
                    },
                    items: [{
                        html: content,
                        title:'Navigation',
                        autoScroll: true,
                        border: false,
                        iconCls: 'nav'
                    },{
                        title:'Settings',
                        html: content,
                        border: false,
                        autoScroll: true,
                        iconCls: 'settings'
                    }]
                },{
                    id: 'app-portal', //Creates the panel where the portal drop zones are.
                    xtype: 'mainpanel',
                    region: 'center',
                    items: [{
                        id: 'col-1', //Each column represents a drop zone column. If we add more there are more created and width gets adjusted accordingly
                        items: [{
                            id: 'portlet-1',
                            title: 'Portlet 1',
                            html: content,
                            listeners: {
                                'close': Ext.bind(this.onPortletClose, this)
                        },{
                            id: 'portlet-2',
                            title: 'Portlet 2',
                            html: content,
                            listeners: {
                                'close': Ext.bind(this.onPortletClose, this)
                            }
                        }]
                    },{
                        id: 'col-2',
                        items: [{
                            id: 'portlet-3',
                            title: 'Portlet 3',
                            html: content,
                            listeners: {
                                'close': Ext.bind(this.onPortletClose, this)
                            }
                        }]
                    },{
                        id: 'col-3',
                        items: [{
                            id: 'portlet-4',
                            title: 'Portlet 4',
                            html: content,
                            listeners: {
                                'close': Ext.bind(this.onPortletClose, this)
                            }
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        });
```

The problem is that Ext.bind cannot read the `onPortletClose` function and the browser gives me a:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined` error. I checked the stack and essentially in the Ext.bind(fn,scope) the `fn` is undefined and thus it cannot read the handler function. The difference between my application and in the example is that I add this directly into a JSP's `Ext.onReady()` whereas in the example all of this is added through a `Ext.apply(this, {...})`. I'm really confused. I tried all kinds of gimmicks to force the scope on the viewport but it seems that whatever is inside `Ext.bind()` loses contact with outside or something. I've used `Ext.bind()` before and it went fine although it was inside an `initComponent` configuration. Is that mandatory? If no then what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to understand the meaning of `this` here (or in general when working with JavaScript or ExtJS).

In a global context, `this` refers to the global object, also known as the global `window` variable. This is the case inside your `Ext.onReady` function:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    console.log(this === window);
    // -> true
    // because this is the global object
});
```

In an object context, **by default** `this` refers to the owner object of the function (there are ways around it and actually this is exactly want you want do achieve using `Ext.bind`):

```
var obj = {
   prop: 'My text property',
   fn: function() {
       console.log(this.prop);
       // -> My text property
       // because "this" refers to our object "obj"
   }
};
```

Now, this is exactly what makes the difference between your case and the one from the examples.

When using the approach with `Ext.onReady` `this` - as pointed out above - will refer to the global object, which of course does not have a function `onPortletClose`.

When using the approach from the examples, `this` is accessed from inside of `initComponent`, which is a member function of your derived viewport class, and therefore `this` refers to the component instance (= the owning object), which allows you to access your function.

```
Ext.define('MyViewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',

    onPortletClose: function(portlet) {
        this.showMsg('"' + portlet.title + '" was removed');
    },

    initComponent: function() {
        console.log(this);
        // -> the instance of your viewport class

        Ext.apply(this, {
            items:[{
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'Portlet 1',
                listeners: {
                    'close': Ext.bind(this.onPortletClose, this)
                }
            }]
        });

        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

### Side notes

#### Ext.apply

[`Ext.apply`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext-method-apply) really just copies all properties from one object to another, so in this case it is just a convenient way of *applying* all attributes of that object to `this` with one function call. You could as well just use:

```
this.items = [...];
```

#### Changing the scope of your listeners

You do not need to use `Ext.bind` when adding listeners to a component, you can simply provide a `scope` configuration in your `listeners` object:

```
listeners: {
    close: function() {...},
    scope: this
}
```

### External sources

If you want to dive in a little deeper (which I would recommend), you might want to read more about *this* at the [MDN (Mozilla Developer Network)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: +1 great writeup, whenever someone is having issues with understanding the context of `this` I'll refer them to this answer.

Comment: You're right about the Ext.bind scoping the global window object. However the way you propose to change the listener scope doesn't work. Neither does adding it inside the event object...

Comment: Works fine for me. See [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/812) for a demonstration.