# Accessing event arguments in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, event-handling, arguments

Generally when we create event handlers we go like this:

```
boxready: function (me, width, height, eOpts) {
  me.X() <-refers to the component whose event is triggered and calls the function X()
}
```

However I am in a situation where I want to do this:

```
boxready: {
  fn: Ext.bind(this.myFunction, this),
  scope: me
}
```

But since I don't use `function(me, ...)` I cannot access the arguments the event sends. Is there a way for me to access them in order to put them in the scope property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to set the scope twice? Either use the `scope` configuration (preferred) **or** `Ext.bind`. Also you're calling `Ext.bind` on the return value of `myFunction`, which does not make sense unless `myFunction` returns a function itself.

**Suggested approach:**

```
listeners: {
    boxready: function(me, width, height, eOpts) {
        //...
    },
    scope: this
}
```

or if you have multiple listeners which need different scopes:

```
listeners: {
    boxready: {
        fn: function(me, width, height, eOpts) {
            //...
        },
        scope: this
    },
    destroy: {
        fn: function() {},
        scope: this.otherScope
    }
}
```

**Also works, but not recommended:**

```
listeners: {
    boxready: Ext.bind(function(me, width, height, eOpts) {
        //...
    }, this)
}
```

Comment: Must the scope: always be relative to `this`? My problem is that the way I have put things together `this` points to the global window object. What I want is to change it to my viewport, but even if I do: `Ext.bind(this.myFunction, Ext.getCmp('viewportId'))` it still doesn't work... Neither will `function(){this},scope: Ext.getCmp('viewport')`. In that case it points to the panel that has the handler.

Comment: I suppose you refer to the code sample your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24913743/ext-bind-does-not-see-function-in-extjs). The problem there is, that you are just creating the viewport (i.e. it does not exist yet), so naturally you cannot set it as the scope at this time.